# RSS Reader error

Tags: iphone

I am currently doing an application which make use of the RSS Feed from http://www.learnerstogether.net/. However i keep getting the error unable to download the XML data from the website. Can someone tell me what is wrong.

```
@implementation Parser
@synthesize items, responseData;
@synthesize currentTitle;
@synthesize currentDate;
@synthesize currentSummary;
@synthesize currentLink;
@synthesize currentPodcastLink;

- (void)parseRssFeed:(NSString *)url withDelegate:(id)aDelegate {
    [self setDelegate:aDelegate];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:url] retain];


    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL];

    [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download xml data (Error code %i )", [error code]];

    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSXMLParser *rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];

    [rssParser setDelegate:self];

    [rssParser parse];
}

#pragma mark rssParser methods

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    currentElement = [elementName copy];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        self.currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.currentPodcastLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    // podcast url is an attribute of the element enclosure
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"enclosure"]) {
        [currentPodcastLink appendString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [item setObject:self.currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:self.currentLink forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:self.currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
        [item setObject:self.currentPodcastLink forKey:@"podcastLink"];

        // Parse date here
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"E, d LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"]; // Thu, 18 Jun 2010 04:48:09 -0700
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.currentDate];

        [item setObject:date forKey:@"date"];

        [items addObject:[item copy]];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [self.currentTitle appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [self.currentLink appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [self.currentSummary appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [self.currentDate appendString:string];
        NSCharacterSet* charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \n"];
        [self.currentDate setString: [self.currentDate stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: charsToTrim]];
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(receivedItems:)])
        [_delegate receivedItems:items];
    else
    { 
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                    format:@"Delegate doesn't respond to receivedItems:"];
    }
}

#pragma mark Delegate methods

- (id)delegate {
    return _delegate;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id)new_delegate {
    _delegate = new_delegate;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [items release];
    [responseData release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: your question is horrible to read,Please edit your question where exactly get crashed using Back Trace command of GDB console.

Comment: If you want to parse RSS on the iPhone, I would recommend taking a look at [FeedParser](https://github.com/kballard/feedparser).

Answer (score 0):

Your error has absolutely nothing to do with the RSS parsing aspect of this. What's more, you haven't even pasted in the full error. You should log the error object itself in your implementation of `-connection:didFailWithError:`. That should give you a human-readable description of what went wrong.